# Ubuntu 16.04 - Did 'apt-get upgrade' and now Intel Graphics Driver doesn't work

Tags: drivers, upgrade, graphics, nvidia-optimus

I have a Optimus Laptop, MSI GS70 Stealth Pro 6QE. It comes with a Intel® HD Graphics 530 (CPU Integrated) and a Nvidia GeForce GTX 970M 3GB GDDR5.

After upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 and switching from Nvidea drivers to the intel one, I am unable to enter my desktop.

It freezes after I type my password and press 'enter'. (I can't even access the terminals with 'Ctrl-Alt-F1')

I installed the Nvidia graphics from the [Graphics Drivers Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and the Intel Graphics from [their own website](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2).

Comment: What is your laptop make and model? Nvidia GT number? CPU?

Comment: Can you list the commands you ran to blacklist Nvidia?

Comment: Also what Nvidia driver was installed and how did you install it? It makes a lot of difference when updating kernels...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I didn't blacklist Nvidia, I just switched them with prime (`prime-select nvidia`) and couldn't log in with the Intel Driver, only with the Nvidia one.

Comment: So after Intel lockup you power off and can switch to Nvidia drivers using grub commands and rhen boot and Ubuntu works???

Comment: Yes, it locks after I type my password, so I have to power off, then boot to login screen, Ctrl-Alt-F1 and use `prime-select nvidia`.

Comment: Correction, I don't use grub commands. Ubuntu boots until the Login Screen.

Answer (score 1):

Nvidia drivers have know complications with Ubuntu. The Intel website you link ([intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2))lists many known complications with Linux and Ubuntu specifically.

The first step would be to go to `System Settings`, `Software & Updates` and select the `Additional Drivers` screen which looks like this:

[image]

**Unknown:Unknown** means **Intel Corporation: {Your CPU}**. If it is turned off then turn it on. If it is turned on then turn it off. Reboot and see if this corrects problem.

The second step is to go to the Intel Graphics Installer forum: [graphics-installer-discussions](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/forum/graphics-installer-discussions) and post your problem there.

The third step is to remove **Intel Graphics For Linux OS** you installed and use the native i915 driver in Ubuntu instead. This driver should be automatically used after removing the Intel Web Site's driver.

Comment: I tried turning Intel Drivers off, nothing changed. I forgot to mention, I installed the **Intel Graphics For Linux** after the problem started occurring to see if it was a solution. Is there a way to see why it crashed in logs?

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues You can search for more detailed instructions but basically `journalctl` in the terminal will let you press Home, End, PgUp and PgDn. You can use `gksu gedit /var/log/syslog` and `gksu gedit /var/log/kern.log`. Nvidia might keep it's own log files somewhere? I'd have to research that one.

Comment: Well I couldn't find the solution. The `kern.log` shows multiple `\00` at the time of the freeze.

Comment: `\00` isn't good. I've read a bit about this but can't offer much help. How about two boot menu options, one with Nvidia running, the other with plain jane Ubuntu Intel i915 driver running and Nvidia blacklisted?

Comment: How do I blacklist nvidia drivers?

Comment: Search on 'blacklist Nvidia' in AskUbuntu. I'd do it and provide the link but I'm my phone.